# Second Legend in Plotly based on color

Tags: r, plotly, legend

I've hit a wall trying to solve my problem, and haven't found a helpful solution online. Here's a sample of the data I'm plotting (but it's like this for thousands of lines):

```
df <- data.frame(Institution = c('Inst1', 'Inst2', 'Inst3', 'Inst4', 'Inst5', 'Inst6', 'Inst7'), Score = c(120, 750, 1380, 560, 630, 640, 990), Measure1 = c(100, 500, 600, 700, 300, 400, 550), Measure2 = c(1.2, 1.5, 2.3, 0.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.8), Country = c('China', 'China', 'Norway', 'USA', 'France', 'USA', 'USA'), Colors = c('#ff0000', '#ff0000', '#71C671', '#808080', '#00BCDD', '#808080', '#808080'), CriteriaX = c('no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes'))
```

I'm using Plotly to simultaneously plot this data in two ways: by the top 20 institutions (ranked by their Score), and according to CriteriaX. Here's my code:

```
top_twenty <- df %>% filter(rank(desc(df$Score))<=20)
critX <- data.frame(df[df$CriteriaX == "yes",])

g = plot_ly() %>%
    add_trace(data = top_twenty, 
              x = ~Measure1, 
              y = ~Measure2, 
              type = 'scatter',
              mode = 'markers',
              name = 'Top 20',
              marker = list(size = 20,
                            opacity = 0.5,
                            color = ~as.character(Colors)) %>%
    add_trace(data = critX, 
              x = ~Measure1,
              y = ~Measure2,
              type = 'scatter',
              mode = 'markers',
              name = 'Criteria X',
              marker = list(size = 10,
                            opacity = 0.5, 
                            color = 'green')) %>%
    add_trace(data = top_twenty,
              x = ~Measure1, 
              y = ~Measure2,
              type = 'scatter',
              mode = 'markers',
              showlegend = F,
              marker = list(size = 0.1,
                            color = ~as.character(Colors),
                            colorbar = list(len = 0.8, 
                                            y = 0.3,
                                            title = 'Country')))
```

What I'm trying to do is retain the size-related legend generated from the first two traces, but also create an additional legend based on the color of the countries plotted. The third trace is this attempt (but doesn't work).

I'm stuck on figuring out how to populate a color bar with my hex colors and the corresponding country names. The colors must come from the preset hex colors in my dataset (again, which is huge).

Also, it doesn't have to be a color bar--mainly, I'd like to have two legends. One based on a predetermined hex color from my dataset, one based on plot marker size (top 20 / criteria X). I'd also like the color-based legend to include the corresponding country name as a label.

Help?

Comment: why do you have `showlegend = F,` in the third trace if you want it to make a legend?

Comment: Because when showlegend = T, just one additional marker appears in the legend (the name of the trace). I don't want to append the size-related legend, I want to create a second one based on color.